# how to detect arabic input in TDBEdit

Tags: delphi, arabic

I have TDBEdit how I forced the user to write in Arabic only

**How To Detect Arabic Input in (TDBEdit) in Delphi ?**

Comment: Use the `OnChange` event to check that each character belongs to one  of the [Arabic blocks in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode)

Comment: give me exemple for one character only ,So as not to prolong you

Comment: what if i use **Onkeypress** event `if Key in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'] then
Key := #0;`

Comment: @AsadAlamdar no that will not work, what Tom suggested is better.

Comment: @AsadAlamdar what delphi version are you using

Comment: Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7

Comment: **OnKeyPress** event It works for me (there seem to be loopholes),but why what Tom suggested is better @Abdelillah

Comment: consider someone from  russia or france is using the app (or just some arab switch his keyboard to french ) your code will not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the article Tom mentioned you can achieve what you want:

The article: [Arabic blocks in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode).

Check for the following inputs

```
procedure TForm8.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Caption := 'arabic';
  case integer(key) of
    1536..1791,1872..1919,2208..2303,-1200..-513,-400..-257,8,32,48..57:
       begin
       end;
  else
    // intervene here by setting key = #0
    Caption :=key+ ': is not an arabic character';
end;
```

The numbers above are the decimal representation of the HEX values in the article.

Comment: @AsadAlamdar You got the Idea then, modify it as you please.

Comment: Sorry @Abdelillah, I wanted everyone to benefit when the answer is complete.

Comment: @AsadAlamdar Done.I added numbers also.

Comment: **Thank you so much** @Abdelillah